# Jasmine clock not working with cookie expirations

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, cookies, jasmine

I just wrote a spec in Jasmine which is failing and I don't see why. I'm trying to write a cookie with an expiration date and then checking after the expiration whether it's still available or not. Currently it looks like it's not being removed. Here's my code:

```
 beforeAll(function() {
    jasmine.clock().install();
 });
 it('succesfully sets a cookie with time', function() {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + 1*60*1000); // in milliseconds
        document.cookie = 'testCookieWithTime=helloWorld;path=/;max-age='+1*60+';expires='+d.toUTCString()+';';
        jasmine.clock().mockDate();
        jasmine.clock().tick(650000); //millis

        var v = document.cookie.match('(^|;) ?' + 'testCookieWithTime' + '=([^;]*)(;|$)');

        expect(v[2]).not.toBeDefined();
    });
 afterAll(function() {
    jasmine.clock().uninstall();
 });
```

Unfortunately this is the result of my testrun:

```
Summary (1 tests failed)
X Cookies methods specs succesfully sets a cookie with time
Expected 'helloWorld' not to be defined.
```

I've set the cookie expiration to 1 minute for testing purposes and replaced some variables with numbers (because my code was split up over methods). Probably it's something small, but I can't find it. Help is very much appreciated.

For what it's worth, the getting and setting code of a cookie is based on: https://plainjs.com/javascript/utilities/set-cookie-get-cookie-and-delete-cookie-5/

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
it('succesfully sets a cookie with time', function() {
    cookie_set_method(); 
    jasmine.clock().install();
    jasmine.clock().tick(4000); //millis
    expect(Cookie_get_method()).toEqual(false); //does not exist
    jasmine.clock().uninstall();
});
```

I'm not entirely sure what was going on, but I did mix some things up.